# Allow .htaccess RewriteCond redirect exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite

Here's representation of my current .htaccess file, which I use to proxy to an internal service:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)admin(.*) https://some/path/forbidden.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule uri1/(.*)$ http://localhost:30000/$1 [P]
RewriteRule uri2/(.*)$ http://localhost:30001/$1 [P]
```

It works great, but I want to allow a single exception for "admin/reset", but continue to 301 on any other uri that contains "admin".  How might I do this?

Comment: `admin(?!/reset)` - It's called a look-ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !admin/reset
RewriteRule (.*)admin(.*) https://some/path/forbidden.html [L,R=301]
```